# 2 similar C programs with macro producing different output

Tags: c, gcc, macros

The following code prints nothing:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define TOTAL_SIZE ( (sizeof(array))/(sizeof(array[0])) )
int main()
{
    int array[]={1,2,3}, d;
    for(d=-1; d<=TOTAL_SIZE-2; ++d)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[d+1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

d=-1 <=3-2
       prints array[-1+1] which is array[0]
   d=0  <=3-2
       prints array[0+1] which is array[1]
   d=1  <=3-2
       prints array[1+1] which is array[2]

But not even a single element is printed!

But the this code produces the right output of printing all the elements in the array:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define TOTAL_SIZE ( (sizeof(array))/(sizeof(array[0])) )
int main()
{
    int array[]={1,2,3}, d;
    for(d=0; d<=TOTAL_SIZE-1; ++d)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[d]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the net effect of both the loops seem to be the same.

If we replace the macro `TOTAL_SIZE` with the number of elements in the array, it works. So the problem appears to be with the macro.

But when I try to print the value generated by `TOTAL_SIZE`, it prints the correct value.

What is the problem with the first program?

Comment: Enable all warnings and treat them as errors. It's the only way to remain sane. For gcc and clang, that's `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your macro is that `sizeof` returns an `size_t` which is an *unsigned* integer type that you are comparing to a *signed* `int`. The solution is to cast your size to an `int`.

`#define TOTAL_SIZE (int)( (sizeof(array))/(sizeof(array[0])) )`

Comment: Nitpick, it returns `size_t` which is an implementation defined unsigned integer type, but not necessarily **the** `unsigned int` type.

Comment: yes, but size_t is *unsigned*. thanks for the correction :)

Comment: So my problem was comparing the initial value of d (which is a signed number ie, -1 ) with the size_t returned by sizeof. Thanks for helping out.